# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException

Tags: web-services, ssl, wsdl, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11g to create and run a web service client from an existing WSDL. I keep getting the following error when trying to run. I have added the said certificate to my cacerts file but still same issue. Please help!

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090542]Certificate chain received from localhost - 127.0.0.1 --> direct.dnb.com was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure. Check the certificate chain to determine if it should be trusted or not. If it should be trusted, then update the client trusted CA configuration to trust the CA certificate that signed the peer certificate chain. If you are connecting to a WLS server that is using demo certificates (the default WLS server behavior), and you want this client to trust demo certificates, then specify -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust on the command line for this client.
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I resolved it. For JDeveloper the certs need to be added to another file. Refer to this https://community.oracle.com/thread/2406629